# Combining related probabilties

Tags: statistics

I need to calculate the probability of both L and D occurring P(L,D), but they are not mutually independent. I have estimated the probability of P(L) and P(D) with two distinct models and I also know P(L|D) and P(D|L). As far as I can see it I have two different estimates of P(L,D):

```
P(L) * P(D|L) and 
P(D) * P(L|D)
```

am I best off just averaging these two estimates for a combined P(L,D)?

Comment: I suspect you might get better answers on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

These two ways of computing the joint distribution should be the same to within numerical precision.  If your algorithms are giving you different answers for these two ways, it is a bug in your code.

For a pair of binary variables, all that you need to do is maintain the occurence count
of each of the four outcomes: `(L,D), (!L,D), (L,!D), (!L,!D)`.
If we let `Z=N(L,D)+N(!L,D)+N(L,!D)+N(!L,!D)`

then the probability you care about is just:

```
P(L,D)=N(L,D)/Z
```

The other (marginal, conditional) probabilities are:

```
P(L)=[N(L,D)+N(L,!D)]/Z
P(D)=[N(L,D)+N(!L,D)]/Z

P(L | D ) = N(L,D)/[ N(L,D)+N(!L,D)]
P(D | L ) = N(L,D)/[ N(L,D)+N(L,!D)]
```

with a little algebra you can see that `P(L|D)P(D)=N(L,D)/Z=P(D|L)P(L)`

This points to how one could combine disparate estimates into a single one: convert them back into "counts" and then add these counts.  A case where this could occur is wheen we have two **independent** samples `S1`, `S2`.  Suppose that you estimated
`P(L |D ), P(D)` from sample `S1` and `P(D |L), P(L)` from sample `S2`.  In addition
to the probabilities, we'll need to know count of the the number of samples in each of the samples: `N1,N2`.  Note: the results only depend on the ratio `N1/N2`, so if you didn't have the counts, but knew that the sample sizes were always the same, you could substitute `N1=N2=1` in what follows.

```
N(L,D | S1 ) = N1*P(L | D) P(D)
N(L,D | S2 ) = N2*P(D | L) P(L)

N(L,D | S1+S2) = N(L,D|S1)+N(L,D|S2)
P(L,D | S1+S2) = N(L,D|S1+S2)/(N1+N2)
```

Which in the case of `N1==N2` is just averaging them; but that is only true in the special case where the sample size is the same;  otherwise the result is a weighted average.

This is a simplified version of Bill's answer to [this question on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72935/calculating-joint-probabilities-from-conditional-probabilities) which handles the cases where the estimators may be correlated and/or involve estimating quantities other than empirical probabilities.

Comment: P(L) and P(D) are produced by different estimation models. They are not true probabilities.

Comment: If they don't satisfy the axioms of probability theory, then you probably shouldn't treat them/describe them as such; in which case your question is "how do I combine two arbitrary heuristic measures of belief?", which is ill formed.  But anyway, I've added additional description of how to combine things that might help, but really, the answer is: estimate the probabilities directly.